# Time Machine: How to deal with backups consistently reporting "disk was disconnected" error

Tags: time-machine

My several latest Time Machine backups are consistently reporting the following error when I try to restore from any of them:

> "The backup disk was disconnected while restoring from the backup. Use a reliable network connection while restoring"

For any of the earlier backups on the same network-attached drive, restoring works just fine, for the very same network connection and setup.

---

**Is it my best bet to simply delete those problematic backups from Time Machine? Will Time Machine still be able to perform incremental backups basing on my earlier snapshot as a baseline?**

---

RESEARCH DONE: [This post at Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/6p3vl0/comment/dkms6qe/) is the only piece I could find. It doesn't help to continue backing up to the problematic disk, though.

Comment: Do you have any other Time Machine backup devices, and if so, can you restore from them? You must have more than one backup device anyway to be safe, even if there are no errors.

Comment: Yes, I have both another HDD holding a Time Machine backup. And earlier backups on the network-attached disk in question that are more or less the same as the most recent backups. Still the original question applies.

Comment: I suppose there is no harm in trying to delete the faulty snapshots (if that's what they are) as long as you're sure of your other backup. But in your place, I wouldn't trust anything in that backup anymore, and probably not the device either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done just that: deleted all those problematic backups from Time Machine.

Newer backups are still incremental basing on my earlier snapshot as a baseline.

Made sure I can successfully restore from the newly created backup.